# Discord.py onmessage role allocation issue

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying to work this out but can't work out what i'm doing wrong, the method worked fine to delete and display the message but when I tried to get it to allocate a role at the same time I broke it

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
  for badword in file:
    if badword in msg.content.lower():
      role = discord.utils.get(msg.guild.roles, name="Muted")
      await msg.author.add_roles(role)
      await msg.delete()
      await msg.channel.send(f'{msg.author.mention}! That was a bad word! You have been muted!')
    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

I presume i'm missing something simple?

This is the error i'm  getting:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 283, in on_message
    await msg.author.add_roles(role)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 676, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Also the above is making my other bot.commands repeat indefinitely. So now when I use the random quote command it never stops til I shut off the bot:

```
#wisdom function
@bot.command(help="Wisdom function",
             brief="Get a random wise quote")
async def wisdom(ctx):
  responses = open('quotes.txt').read().splitlines()
  random.seed(a=None)
  response = random.choice(responses)
  await ctx.send(f'Hey {ctx.message.author.mention} here is your wisdom:')
  await ctx.send(response)
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Hi - this question could be improved by explaining more about what is meant by "I broke it" - do you have input/output data examples of both success and "i broke it"?

Comment: Update post with error message and also this is cousin my other commands to repeat indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to @Frederick Reynolds post about your errors in reading the textfile. I can point out a few things as well, however. For your `on_message` function, you never check if the message is from your own bot itself, which triggers the repetition of the function. To avoid this, add `if msg.author == bot.user: return` at the beginning of this function. Secondly, `role = discord.utils.get(msg.guild.roles, name="Muted")` is not able to find the `Muted` role for some reason, which is why it sets the value of `role` to `None`. This is why, when you call `await msg.author.add_roles(role)`, you're basically doing `await msg.author.add_roles(None)`. Lastly, your indentation is wrong, as you are awaiting `bot.process_comands(msg)` for `every badword in file`. Here's the fixed code for the function

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author == bot.user:
        return
    for badword in file:
        if badword in msg.content.lower():
            role = discord.utils.get(msg.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            await msg.author.add_roles(role)
            await msg.delete()
            await msg.channel.send(f'{msg.author.mention}! That was a bad word! You have been muted!')
    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
                             ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

The problem here is `discord.utils.get` cannot find a role called Muted, so it returns a NoneType. When you are trying to assign the role, you are essentially doing `msg.author.add_roles(None)`. Maybe try making sure that the role exists, or referencing it by ID instead of Name.

Edit: You should also (in your quote function) send the quote in the same message as the first. (By using `\n` as a line-break)

Edit 2: You should use a `with` block to readlines from your file, because with what you have now, the file never closes. Also, `read()` returns a string, you cannot do `readlines()` off of the string. Instead do `readlines()` off of the file object.

Edit 3: You are processing commands for every badword in file (why it runs forever)